# Working with Sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

a. Find the next two terms of the sequence

b. Find a recurrence relation that generates the sequence (supply the initial value of the index and the first term of the sequence)

c. Find an explicit formula for the general nth term of the sequence

${1,-2,3,-4,5,...}$

The next two terms are easy $-6$, $7$ but I can't find a recurrence relation or formula.

Comment: The general term is $T(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot n$

Answer (score 1):

A recurrence formula where $n$ appears only in the subscripts is $$f_{n+1}=-2f_n-f_{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy for you to find an *explicit* formula. And if you are given the explicit formula of a sequence so that
$$a_n=f(n)$$
then you can always use
$$a_{n+1}=f(f^{-1}(a_n)+1)$$
as a recursive formula.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

it is an alternate sequence.
$$u_n=(-1)^{n+1}n $$

or

$$u_1=1$$
and
$$u_{n+1}=-u_n+(-1)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+(-1)^n(2n+1).$$